# Removing Items from a List Box after setting the DataSource

Tags: vb.net

I have a small requirement and that is as follows:

I am populating a ListBox using stored procedures and the ListBox is populated as follows:

lstItems.DisplayMember = "emp_name"
lstItems.ValueMember = "login_id"
lstItems.DataSource = accessFunction.getEmployees

The ListBox gets populated correctly. After it is populated, i have a CommandButton and on the click event of the button, i want to remove selected items from the ListBox. So in the click event of the CommandButton, i have written the following code:

lstItems.Items.Remove(lstItems.SelectedItem)

After selecting an item from the ListBox and when i click the CommandButton, i get an error as "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set".

Can anyone, please help me as to how i can delete items from the ListBox.

Regards,
George

Answer (score 0):

Two easy things to try:

1. Rather than databind, you could fill your list with a loop. Remember to add proper NULL handling (I didn't):

   For each dr as DataRow in myDataTable.Rows
     newItem = new ListItems(dr("login_id"), dr("emp_name"))
     lstItems.Add newItem
   Next
2. Save the datatable from your accessFunction in a variable. Delete the row from the datatable and rebind.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the instructions in the Error message and instead of removing item from `ListBox`, remove it from `DataSource` itself (whatever is returned from `accessFunction.getEmployees`).